# How do you configure a WinRT component to run in MTA?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-runtime

With Visual Studio 11 and Win 8 CP... I have an existing in process COM DLL which registers itself to run in the multithreaded apartment (MTA).  I want to convert this over to a WinRT component.  Googling, I haven't even been able to determine whether this is a supported configuration for WinRT components.

Can WinRT components be configured to run MTA?  If so, how do you configure that in VS11?

Comment: This is a slightly confusing question. You want to change the COM server into a managed WinRT component? If its managed WinRT then the threading model is irrelevant, especially Free threaded ones.

Comment: I guess the question is slightly confusing because I'm confused too.  When I created the COM object I had to register it to be free threaded.  No need to do that anymore with WinRT?  Then the question is are WinRT components free threaded or apartment threaded?  Having the WinRT in a single threaded apartment will not work.